# Sqliteopenhelper not calling onCreate for sqlcipher

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, sqlcipher

I have read SQLcipher guid, and all steps are done under the guidance. The onCreate() in SQliteOpenHelper is never been called. Many ways have been tried, all doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

The code is following:

```
package com.example.sqlcipher;

import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;

import com.example.sqlcipher.PasswordContract.Entries;
import com.example.sqlcipher.PasswordContract.Fields;
import com.example.sqlcipher.PasswordContract.GroupFields;
import com.example.sqlcipher.PasswordContract.Groups;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = "MyDatabaseHelper";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fingerprint_key.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public interface Tables {
    public static final String ENTRIES = "entries";
    public static final String FIELDS = "fields";
    public static final String GROUP_FIELDS = "group_fields";
    public static final String GROUPS = "groups";
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "----------create DatabaseHelper--------------");

}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "----------create DatabaseHelper------1--------");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "-----------on Create--------------");
    createTables(sqLiteDatabase);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

}

/**
 * create Tables for database.
 */
public void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "create the strings of sql !");
    final String entriesSql = "create table if not exists "
            + Tables.ENTRIES + "("
            + Entries._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Entries.TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + Entries.NOTES + " TEXT,"
            + Entries.GROUP_ID + " INTEGER"
            + ")";

    final  String fieldsSql = "create table if not exists "
            + Tables.FIELDS + "("
            + Fields._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Fields.TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + Fields.VALUE + " TEXT,"
            + Fields.ENTRY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + Fields.GROUPFIELD_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + Fields.IS_HIDDEN + " INTEGER"
            + ")";

    final String groupFieldsSql = "create table if not exists "
            + Tables.GROUP_FIELDS + "("
            + GroupFields._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + GroupFields.TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + GroupFields.GROUP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + GroupFields.IS_HIDDEN + " INTEGER"
            + ")";

    final String groupsSql = "create table if not exists "
            + Tables.GROUPS + "("
            + Groups._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Groups.TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + Groups.ICON + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    db.execSQL(entriesSql);
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "create table entries");
    db.execSQL(fieldsSql);
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "create table filed");
    db.execSQL(groupFieldsSql);
    db.execSQL(groupsSql);
    LogUtil.dLog(TAG, "create tables is over! ");
    initDatabase(db);
}

private void initDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String insertIntoGroups = "INSERT INTO groups " +
            "(" + "title, icon" +
            ")" +
            "VALUES";

}


}
```

The place where call SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DatabaseHelper mHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, 
            DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    mHelper.getWritableDatabase(FingerPrintProvider.PASSWORD);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Did the things you tried that didn't work include uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the SQLCipher for Android [test suite](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests) we have a [test](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/VerifyOnUpgradeIsCalledTest.java) that executes both `onCreate` as well as `onUpgrade`.  You should verify what `PRAGMA user_version` returns for your given database, and compare it to what you are providing to your `DatabaseHelper`.  If the database does not exist, `user_version` will return `0`, and when you provide `1` or some number larger than `0`, it will invoke `onCreate`.